# WooCommerce Cart - Adding product variations to the cart based on some id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using `Wordpress` + `WooCommerce`.

There is only one product: "`Shirt`". I let the user input some text to be printed on his shirt.

Then, every time the user orders one shirt with his text one new item should (I want to) be added to the cart. But it is the same product.
For every shirt order with a text an "`id`" will be created.

```
For example, imagine he ordered:
- 2 shirts with the text "Mouse" -> id: 1
- 5 shirts with the text "Horse" -> id: 2
- 1 shirts with the text "Tiger" -> id: 3
```

I want the cart displays 3 entries with the amounts: {2, 5, 1}
and not just 1 entry with the amount: 8.

I want to prevent the cart groups all entries (since it is the same product).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was (in PHP):

```
$product_id = 66;
$quantity_to_add = 1;
$cart_item_data = array(
    "id" => 309
);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity_to_add, 0, array(), $cart_item_data);
```

(modify the values as you need)

Be aware that `$product_id` and `id` have different meanings.